# Let a enemy attack when he sees the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can someone help me I am using the code below to try to let the enemy look if he can see the player or not.

But the problem is can he still see me when I am behind a wall
Can someone help me out ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    float distance;

    public GameObject player;
    public Transform Shootpoint;

    public bool CanSee = false;

    [SerializeField]
    float chaseDistence = 0.5f;



    void Update()
    {
        distance = Vector3.Distance(Shootpoint.position, player.transform.position);

        if (!Physics.Raycast(Shootpoint.position, player.transform.position, chaseDistence))
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(Shootpoint.position, player.transform.position, Color.red);
            CanSee = false;
            Debug.Log("CANT SEE");

        }
        else if (Physics.Raycast(Shootpoint.position, player.transform.position, chaseDistence))
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(Shootpoint.position, player.transform.position, Color.green);
            CanSee = true;
            Debug.Log("CAN SEE");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You arent checking what the raycast hits, only that it hits something...

Comment: can you perhaps tell me how i can check that ?

Comment: Besides doing the raycast twice is redundant and only wastes performance ;)

Answer (score 2):

Like @BugFinder mentioned, you are only checking that the `RayCast` did collide with *something* and not necessarily the player.

If you want to determine if the ray is colliding with only the player, and not another object, use the function overload that sets a `RaycastHit` object. Then you can get the `tag` and compare it with the tag of your player. (see [Physics.RayCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) and [RaycastHit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html))

You could achieve this like so:

```
RaycastHit hitInfo;
if(Physics.Raycast(Shootpoint.position, player.transform.position, out hitInfo, chaseDistence)) 
{
    if (hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("player"))
    {
        // Can see
    }
    else 
    {
        // Can't see, raycast hit something
    }
}
else
{
    // Can't see, raycast hit nothing
}
```